# convert text to image in php

Tags: php

I would like to style a text string taken from a form field and then convert it to a transparent .PNG (alpha BG).

Is this possible with PHP? If so, would you kindly show me how this would be achieved

Comment: You can try this: http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-text-to-image.htm

Answer (score 29):

yes, its very much possible, you are going to follow the same technique as we do while generating a captcha image.

Requirement: GD library should be enabled in your php.

Code (taken from php help file ;)

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 18):

**convert text to image** (php code):

at first, you need to ensure, that the hosting has enabled GD library (in a new php file, execute `phpinfo();` and in output see/find if GD library is enabled) .

## Solution 1 (auto-sized output):

```
TextToImage_my( $text='Helloooo! my unicode words:  ǩ Ƥ Ў  ض ط  Ⴓ ');
    // ==== other parameters can be used too, see the function arguments below
```

function code: [text-to-image.php](https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/text-to-image.php)

## Solution 2 (manual-sized output):

(needs to have manual width&height of output,  longer strings are cut out)..

```
<?php
$text = "YOUR  texttttttttttttttt";

$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );                             //width & height
$background  = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0,   0,   255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, $text, $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the auto-sized solution :)

Comment: one question... is it possible to break line in input text?

Comment: Solution 1 is brilliant!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolordeallocate.php needs TWO parameters, `imagecolordeallocate(GdImage $image, int $color)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = imagecreate(widthyouwant,heightyouwant);
$bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($image,255,255,255,0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
imagettftext($image,fontsize, 0, x, y, $black, "fontlocation", $_GET['text']);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

You could then display the image by going 
I think thats correct, been awhile since I've done this.