# Is there any free php code that transform text into a nice logo?

Tags: php, image, text, text2image, graphical-logo

I would like to have a php function that can take text as the input and generate a nice logo (image) with that text. It would be nice to have a flexibility in the style of the logo (color, shadow, shape, size and so on). Can anybody recommend something?

Comment: GD is about the best you can get with PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php if you want more, you need ImageMagick. e.g. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/

Comment: Well, stack overflow does this. I would look into http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

I just know the [ASCII Generator](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/), but maybe theres a PHP version somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use CSS+HTML to style the text and then generate an image from that using wkHTMLToImage, which is part of the wkHTMLtoPDF project - http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this?, http://trevorrudolph.com/image.php heres the code

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( 400, 200 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "http://trevorrudolph.com",
  $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need another php code for generating that.

Here is how to **[Convert Text To Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488549/convert-text-to-image-in-php)**