# How to turn text file to image

Tags: php, gd

I would like to turn a .txt file into image like png.

How to make it possible by gd in php? Would you kindly show me how this would be achieved

Comment: `rename('file.txt', 'file.png');`

Comment: @Alfwed I hope you are joking .. right?

Comment: See this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488549/convert-text-to-image-in-php

Comment: @Mihai Well it's one possible answer to this vague question.

Comment: @Alfwed: changing the file extension NEVER turned a text into an image!

Comment: Have you done any research yourself (besides coming up with a question title on SO)?

Comment: @jocelyn The OP never said what's in this ".txt" file. It could very well be a png image.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-shot-kill function to do this.

[PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is a big library. You have to go through a few steps:

- grab the text content inside the *.txt file and store it in a variable using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php);
- create an in-memory (png) image of the appropriate dimensions (this will be tricky) and store the image in a variable with [imagecreate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php);
- position the text you grabbed from the file somewhere within the image (this is tricky but corresponds with the previous trickiness) using [imagettftext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) - while making sure you have the *.ttf font files available on the server;
- save or output the image to using [imagepng()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php);

The **tricky** part I previously referenced is calculating the size of the needed image based on the amount of text in the *.txt file and on the font sizes per letter, per row etc..

The second **tricky** part is calculating the positioning of the text in the image so as to not overflow the image boundaries.