# Write text on image using ImageMagick commands

Tags: php, imagick

I want to write text on an image using PHP by calling ImageMagick commands, like uploading an image and editing text on the image. How can I do that?

Comment: What you have tried yet ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of classes that will help you doing this, my favorite is https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage. There is also a stackoverflow post how to convert text into an image [convert text to image in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488549/convert-text-to-image-in-php). With this combination you are able to reach what you want I think.

You'll need the function `->overlay('watermark.png', 'bottom right')` of the *SimpleImage* class.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and i need to resize image by calling imagick commands in php

Comment: @shrutiAkki The SimpleImage has a simple resize function as well.